# List of common Gherkin step starting keywords

Tags: gherkin

I want to compile a list of of keywords in use by my project (but also in the gherkin world).  I am calling these words 'step starting keywords' (aka dark blue words in Rubymine) to clarify exactly what I am looking for.
Below is my current list, but I would like to expand this list, but I have yet to find an index of these words (or even know if there is a word that these words are known as in talking about Gherkin usage.

Examples

```
 Given
 And
 Then
 When
```

Maybe also include the structure keywords

```
 Examples:
 Scenario Outline:
 Feature:
```

Note: My ultimate goal would be to have a 'dictionary' of ALL of the words that I have in use in my Gherkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add 'But' and '*' with step starters list.